# Does anyone success installed Mask R-CNN IN GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis

As title, does anyone success installed [Mask R-CNN](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/i.ann.maskrcnn.html) in GRASS GIS?

Also, I found a script for updating GRASS GIS in order to use MASK R-CNN as below:

To use environment setting flags like `–overwrite`, the user has to update his GRASS GIS with the following patch:

lib/python/script/core.py:

```
    elif var.startswith (b'opt_'):
        options[var[4:]] = val
    elif var in [b'GRASS_OVERWRITE', b'GRASS_VERBOSE']:
-       os.environ[var] = val
+       os.environ[var.decode("utf-8")] = val.decode("utf-8")
    else:
        raise SyntaxError("invalid output from g.parser: %s" %line)
```

How can I update? I'm new to GRASS GIS.

Comment: You could propose the change here: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/master/lib/python/script/core.py but I don't see the original code there. Which GRASS GIS version do you use? Please edit your question and add the version.

Answer (score 1):

These are actually multiple question.

> does anyone success installed Mask R-CNN in GRASS GIS?

Yes.

> How can I update?

As @markusN noted in his comment, you can open a pull request at GRASS GIS [GitHub repository](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass).

However, the GRASS GIS code snippet you have reported was removed/changed in 2018, in [this commit](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/commit/7e1945f230e57b32adda5f23f070f0c2e1525a00). Upgrading your GRASS GIS to version >= 7.8 should solve the issue (the required GRASS GIS version is mentioned in the [documentation of these modules](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/i.ann.maskrcnn.html))

Answer (score 0):

better work in linux environment. the Mask R-CNN  fail to install in GRASS under window environment.

Comment: Some related fixes are on the way, eee https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/pull/524 (not yet merged as of today)

Comment: Meanwhile the changes have been merged, see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/ for i.ann.maskrcnn.train, i.ann.maskrcnn.detect, i.ann.maskrcnn manuals